# QGIS Field Calculator Expression: get field name for value at specific index

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, expression, array

I am looking for a way to search the field name ( green circle ) of a value at a specific index.
[image: Field Name]

In the example shown above I would like to find the field name "25 x 2,3" for the value of y1 & y2.

It would be kind of opposite of the following example where I search a value at a spefic index in a given field:

```
attribute(get_feature_by_id('RohrdimensionierungsTabelle',8),'25 x 2,3')
```

Based of an previous post this is what I have so far : [Expression to retrieve index of specific value](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/475174/qgis-field-calculator-expression-to-retrieve-index-of-specific-value)

```
--MAP ALL FIELD NAMES as key-value pair with their own values, exlude zero

with_variable('array_field',
 array_foreach(
  array_sort(
   array_foreach(             array_filter(map_akeys(attributes(get_feature_by_id('RohrdimensionierungsTabelle',1))),
             @element not ilike 'Volumenstrom [h]'),
             regexp_replace('0'||@element,'^(0)([0-9]{3}|[^0-9])','\\2')    -- add ZERO for sorting -> [0]25 x 2,3
                    )
                ),
                regexp_replace(@element,'^0','') --reomove ZERO after sorting
            ),
    array_foreach(@array_field,
    map(@element,array_remove_all(aggregate(
    layer:='RohrdimensionierungsTabelle',
    aggregate:='array_agg',
    expression:=attribute(@element)),0))))
```

Result: [ { '25 x 2,3': [ '25', '32.7', '41.4', '50.9', '61.4', '72.… }, { '32 x 2,9': [ '25', '32.7', '41.4', '50.9', '61.4', '72.… }, .... etc.

Here I am stuck, I need to somehow find my value in the right key ( field ). The Problem is that I need some kind of expanded knowledge about the index where I got the information in first place. There is the case where a value in the 'RohrdimensionierungsTabelle' can occur more than one time. So not knowing the index where i got the value from can return the wrong field just by searching in the key-value pair.

If it's easier, maybe someone can convert the solution already provided by she_weeds so that the we get the field name as an output.

Comment: Just as a side comment but using field name like yours is asking for trouble (best practice is to avoid space, comma and starting with number in field name...)

Comment: the field name is not fix, I'm flexible regarding renaiming it. It could easaly be something like 25x2,3 or just simple 25  :)

Comment: Fields name are up to you of course, it's just that importing your data in a database will likely fail if let as they are and using SQL will always need your field name to be enclosed in double quote…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way out is, if you have already calculated `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2` per the linked question, then you can build on those.

Use this to get an **array** of field name(s) from the other table where the value matches `y1` (change second line to `2` to get `y2`):

```
with_variable('idx',
              1,          --specify if querying 1 or 2
with_variable('attribs',
              attributes(get_feature('RohrdimensionierungsTabelle',
                                     'Volumenstrom [h]',
                                      eval('x'||@idx))), --get row matching x1/x2
              array_filter(map_akeys(@attribs),
                           @attribs[@element] = eval('y'||@idx))
))
```

Then you just need to sort the resulting array by alphabetical order and get the first value. There are two ways depending on how your fields are named.

- If your field names were *already in alphabetic order* (e.g. `v025_2_5` , `v090_8_2`, `v125_11_4`), **all you need to do is add `[0]` to the end of the above expression** and you have your result.
- But in the example field names you've provided, as in the linked question, we have to once again tediously add a `0` to field names starting with 2 digits, sort the array, then strip out the `0` again per the expression below.

```
with_variable('idx',
              1,          --specify if querying 1 or 2
with_variable('attribs',
              attributes(get_feature('RohrdimensionierungsTabelle',
                                     'Volumenstrom [h]',
                                      eval('x'||@idx))), --get row matching x1/x2
              array_foreach(
                  array_sort(array_foreach(
                                 array_filter(map_akeys(@attribs),
                                                        @attribs[@element] = eval('y'||@idx)),
                                          regexp_replace('0'||@element,'^(0)([0-9]{3}|[^0-9])','\\2'))), --add leading zero and sort
                            regexp_replace(@element,'^0',''))[0] --strip leading zero and get first item in array
))
```

I hope the example above illustrates once again the benefits of proper data structure and field naming.

---

I think Virtual Layer would be much more elegant at generating `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2` and the corresponding field names that `y1` and `y2` were derived from, all in one go — but that should be asked in a separate question and would need a different approach + functions.